# Is it possible to disable Command Substitution in Bash?

Tags: unix, command

Is it possible to disable Command Substitution in Bash?
I want to pass a string containing several backticks characters as command-line argument to a program, without trailing backslashs or quoting the string.
Thank you.

Comment: but .... quoting is exactly the way to do this

Answer (score 4):

I assume there is a misconception which grounds your question.  Quoting *is* most likely the solution to your situation.  But maybe you haven't found the right way of quoting yet or similar.

If your dangerous string shall be verbatim (without quoting or escaping) in the source code, you can put it in a separate file and read it from there:

```
dangerous_string=$(cat dangerous_string_file.txt)
```

If it shall be passed without interpretation to a command, use the double quotes to prevent interpretation:

```
my_command "$dangerous_string"
```

If you have to pass it to a command which needs to receive a quoted version of your string because it is known to carelessly pass the string without using sth like the double quotes to prevent interpretation, you can always use `printf` to get a quoted version:

```
quoted_dangerous_string=$(printf "%q" "$dangerous_string")
careless_command "$quoted_dangerous_string"
```

If all these options do not help in your situation, please explain in more detail where your problem lies.